# iOS - RSA decryption with private_key.pem

Tags: ios, encryption, rsa, pem

I have a private_key file in **pem** format. Previously I wrote a [blog](http://jslim.net/blog/2013/01/05/rsa-encryption-in-ios-and-decrypt-it-using-php/) about encryption in iOS.

But now I googled for few days, unfortunately I can't find a solution.

1. Is **der** format required?
2. How can I read the private_key.pem and parse them to data that could be processed?
3. How do I decrypt using the data that I get?

Comment: That's a good question, i got the same issue